# AngularJS $animation addClass called only on first time

Tags: angularjs, animation, addclass

I have simple function in directive link which is calling

```
$animate.addClass(element, 'wrong')
```

and then animation .wrong

```
m.animation ".wrong", ["$timeout",($timeout)->

 removeClass: (element, className)->
   console.log "remove"
   angular.noop()

 addClass: (element, className) ->
   console.log "add"
   $timeout(->
     element.removeClass(className)
   ,
     500
   )
   return
```

on first run is added class right and called addClass fn in animation. But on second time is  just added class but not called addClass fn. Also removeClass fn is never called.

// CODE IS IN COFFEESCRIPT

// WHEM PLUNKER WILL BE WORKING I'LL PROVIDE EXAMPLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `done()` in your animations in order to remove `ng-animate` so you can change the animations. If you don't call done(), Angular thinks your animation is still running.

```
.animation(".wrong", function(){
    return {
        addClass: function(element, className, done){
            done();
        },
        removeClass: function(element, className, done){
            done();
        }
    };
})
```